# Sharepoint 2010 how to create global web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

is it possible for sharepoint 2010 to create global web parts?

I have 10 pages that would use one web part, I want to create one in a library, then drag and drop it in, and when editing one, it updates across all the pages I inserted this web part.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are looking for is proper scoping. When creating a webpart you have a feature for it. When the webpart is added to a farm solution you may set the scope of the feature to be web app level or farm level (those are the global ones). I suppose web application level is the one you will be interested in. Then you may add webpart deployed like this to any number of pages.

To check more about scoping please check those two links:

- https://www.pritambaldota.com/understanding-features-and-feature-scope-in-sharepoint-2010/
- https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-tools/using-features-and-solutions-to-deploy-your-sharepoint-customizations/

Comment: Thanks, is this possible to allow access this setting at user level? or is it have to admin?

Comment: setting scope is part of deployment process of the solution so you will rather need more admin like permissions to perform such an action. Also to activate a feature and tenant (farm) level or web app level you will need access to SharePoint CA site